# Redirect user to login if not logged in, on specific pages

Tags: users, redirect

I'd like to redirect user to login page on specific pages, after displaying message "You need to login to view this page".
I followed this documentation, but couldn't get through.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this in admin section-

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page() {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page('add page slug or i.d here') &&       
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ) {

    wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/page/' ); 
    exit;
}
```

And for frontend-

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

    if ( is_page('slug') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

        wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/your-page/', 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

And this `auth_redirect` function is for backend. If you want to use it on front end then add the below filter-

```
add_filter( 'auth_redirect_scheme', 'the_dramatistcheck_loggedin' );
function the_dramatist_check_loggedin(){
    return 'logged_in';
}
```

Then `auth_redirect()` will work as expected : redirect users to the login form if they are not logged in.

Comment: Thank you the_dramatist. Can you tell me how to redirect user back to same page, from which user has been redirected to login page, after user has logged in for frontend?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in our file, will you please give us bit of code in which filter or action you are running this code